# Spark Dataframe from a different data format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've this data set. for which I need to create a sparkdataframe in scala. This data is a column in a csv file. column name is dataheader

dataheader

```
"{""date_time"":""1999/05/22 03:03:07.011"",""cust_id"":""cust1"",""timestamp"":944248234000,""msgId"":""113"",""activityTimeWindowMilliseconds"":20000,""ec"":""event1"",""name"":""ABC"",""entityId"":""1001"",""et"":""StateChange"",""logType"":""type123,""lastActivityTS"":944248834000,""sc_id"":""abc1d1c9"",""activityDetectedInLastTimeWindow"":true}"
"{""date_time"":""1999/05/23 03:03:07.011"",""cust_id"":""cust1"",""timestamp"":944248234000,""msgId"":""114"",""activityTimeWindowMilliseconds"":20000,""ec"":""event2"",""name"":""ABC"",""entityId"":""1001"",""et"":""StateChange"",""logType"":""type123,""lastActivityTS"":944248834000,""sc_id"":""abc1d1c9"",""activityDetectedInLastTimeWindow"":true}"
```

I was able to read the csv file -

```
val df_tmp = spark
                    .read
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                    .option("header","true")
                    .option("quoteMode", "ALL")
                    .option("delimiter", ",")
                    .option("escape", "\"")
                    //.option("inferSchema","true")
                    .option("multiline", "true")
                    .load("D:\\dataFile.csv")
```

I tried to split the data into separate columns in a dataframe but did not succeed.

one thing I noticed in data is both key and value are enclosed by double double quotes `""key1"":""value1""`

Comment: What does "did not succeed" mean in this case?

Comment: I was able to read the csv
 `df_tmp: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [text: string]`

`df_tmp.show(false)`
|text
                                                                                                                 
|{"date_time":"1999/05/22 03:03:07.011","cust_id":"cust1","timestamp":944248234000,"msgId":"113","activityTimeWindowMilliseconds":20000,"ec":"event1","name":"ABC","entityId":"1001","et":"StateChange","logType":"type123,"lastActivityTS":944248834000,"sc_id":"abc1d1c9","activityDetectedInLastTimeWindow":true}|

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the output you expect. I have a few ideas to help you but I'm still not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Since it's a json string, I parsed and applied regex to bring it into a dataframe column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the field inside the data field, you need to parse it and write it into a new CSV file.
It's obviously a string in json format